# How to remove non-printable characters

Tags: string, go, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to remove non-printable characters from a string in Golang.

https://play.golang.org/p/Touihf5-hGH

```
invisibleChars := "Douglas​"
fmt.Println(invisibleChars)
fmt.Println(len(invisibleChars))

normal := "Douglas"
fmt.Println(normal)
fmt.Println(len(normal))
```

Output:

```
Douglas​
10
Douglas
7
```

The first string has an invisible char at the end.

I've tried to replace non-ASCII characters, but it removes accents too.

How can I remove non-printable characters only?

Comment: Refer to this [what-is-the-range-of-unicode-printable-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770117/what-is-the-range-of-unicode-printable-characters).
And answer from icza is great.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Foreword:** I released this utility in my [`github.com/icza/gox`](https://github.com/icza/gox) library, see [`stringsx.Clean()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/gox/stringsx#Clean).

---

You could remove runes where [`unicode.IsGraphic()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsGraphic) or [`unicode.IsPrint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsPrint) reports false. To remove certain `rune`s from a string, you may use [`strings.Map()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map).

For example:

```
invisibleChars := "Douglas​"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", invisibleChars)
fmt.Println(len(invisibleChars))

clean := strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
    if unicode.IsGraphic(r) {
        return r
    }
    return -1
}, invisibleChars)

fmt.Printf("%q\n", clean)
fmt.Println(len(clean))

clean = strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
    if unicode.IsPrint(r) {
        return r
    }
    return -1
}, invisibleChars)

fmt.Printf("%q\n", clean)
fmt.Println(len(clean))
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7HS2J2pIDvs)):

```
"Douglas\u200b"
10
"Douglas"
7
"Douglas"
7
```

Answer (score 12):

```golang
invisibleChars = strings.TrimFunc(invisibleChars, func(r rune) bool {
        return !unicode.IsGraphic(r)
    })
```

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/39yWgnnRPXr

Answer (score 2):

Just F.Y.I.,

I often use `strings.TrimFunc`, but I have found that `strings.Map()` detects invisible chars better than `strings.TrimFunc`.

`strings.TrimFunc` can not detect if the input chars are `"Douglas\u200b" + "bar"`. The following example fails if followed by "bar". The result becomes `13` rather than `10`.

```golang
func ExampleTrimFunc() {
    invisibleChars := "Douglas\u200b" + "bar"
    invisibleChars = strings.TrimFunc(invisibleChars, func(r rune) bool {
        return !unicode.IsGraphic(r)
    })

    fmt.Println(invisibleChars)
    fmt.Println(len(invisibleChars))

    normal := "Douglasbar"
    fmt.Println(normal)
    fmt.Println(len(normal))

    // Output:
    // Douglasbar
    // 10
    // Douglasbar
    // 10
}
```

- https://go.dev/play/p/TB-98P081U4 @ Go Playground

However, using `strings.Map()` as follows is successful.

```
 func ExampleTrimFunc() {
    invisibleChars := "Douglas\u200b" + "bar"
-   invisibleChars = strings.TrimFunc(invisibleChars, func(r rune) bool {
-       return !unicode.IsGraphic(r)
-   })
+   invisibleChars = strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
+       if unicode.IsGraphic(r) {
+           return r
+       }
+       return -1
+   }, invisibleChars)
 
    fmt.Println(invisibleChars)
    fmt.Println(len(invisibleChars))
 
    normal := "Douglasbar"
    fmt.Println(normal)
    fmt.Println(len(normal))
 
    // Output:
    // Douglasbar
    // 10
    // Douglasbar
    // 10
 }
```

- https://go.dev/play/p/4ybnKVh2NDZ @ Go Playground